# all products 95 cents decimal woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, decimal, rounding

Hi all I've got a Woocommerce question,

I was wondering if there is a php function that rounds up all the prices to a decimal to .95 cents.

Example:

$5.66 -> $5.95 
$13.23 -> $13.95 
$2.54 -> $ $2.95

Thank you!

Comment: `ceil($price) - 0.05`

Answer (score 0):

there is no built in function for it you need to make your self
`

```html
<?php
echo myPriceFormat(12.94);
echo '<br>';
echo myPriceFormat(12.95);
echo '<br>';
echo myPriceFormat(12.96);
function myPriceFormat($no){
    if( $no<(ceil($no)-0.05) ){
     $no=ceil($no) - 0.05;
    }
    return $no;
}
?>
```

`